# Is it possible that variadic function takes function pointer as argument?

Tags: c, function-pointers, variadic-functions

The title says it all. Can function be passed as argument in variadic function and if so, how can I access it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>

void func(double x, int n, ...){
    va_list fs;
    va_start(fs, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        va_arg(fs, *); //this is where I get confused
    }
    
}

int main(){
    double x = 60.0 * M_PI / 180.0;
    func(x, 3, &cos, &sin, &exp);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `va_args` is the type to convert to.  In this case each function has compatible types, specifically they take a single `double` as an argument and return a `double`.  The type of a pointer to such a function is `double (*)(double)`, so that it what you would use for the type.

```
double (*f)(double) = va_arg(fs, double (*)(double));
double result = f(x);
```

Also, don't forget to call `va_end(fs);` after the loop.